# undeclared local variable 'session' in python

Tags: python

I am doing a script which intercepts our VoIP data and uses a session to keep track of how many times the phone rings in order to see what part of the script to execute. I get an error early on which says session is an undeclared local variable. I do not understand how that could be possible when I import session from flask. Here is the relevent section of my code:

```
import os, sys, json, requests, time
import datetime
from flask import Flask, request, Response,session
#from flask_session import Session 
from twilio.rest import Client
#from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app= Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key= 'a secret key'
#app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
#sess= Session()
@app.route('/', methods =['POST'])

def respond() :

    if str(request.json['payload']['source_number']) in session:
       session[request.json['payload']['source_number']] +=1
       print(session[request.json['payload']['source_number']])
   else:
        temp_list = session
        temp_list.append(dict({request.json['payload']['source_number'],1}))
        session = temp_list
   #if request is line.ringing, display the caller name and number
```

Comment: as you have an assignment `session = temp_list` in your `respond()` function. `session` is a local variable to that function.

if you wanted to use the global session you would have to declare it as `global`.

Comment: but, you don't show where `session` variable is assigned prior to  the `if` statement... I would pass it as an argument to `respond` (probably along with `request` variable) and use them as local inside that function.

Comment: I got it going, but it turns out that sessions don't persist with web hooks, so I will need to store my data locally like in a CSV file.